# Prestashop add custom radio button on shipping carriers on front end checkout

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I have created one custom module in Prestashop 1.7.8.7 which will add multiple shipping methods (Carrier) and will show shipping cost based on product dimensions and delivery address. So shipping carrier will look something like this on front-end checkout page. https://prnt.sc/E1avDASyJYYW

Now if someone select **SameDay Courier Shipping** then i need to show two radio button to select which service they want.
It will have two radio options like

1. Delivery pickup (by default this option will be selected)
2. Locker pickup

So if someone select **Delivery pickup** then it will have different shipping cost and if someone select **Locker pickup** then it will have different shipping cost.

Can anybody help me how can i achieve this functionality.

While digging, i found that we have file called **DeliveryOptionsFinder.php** and in that file we have one public function called **getDeliveryOptions()** where we have this line of code

```
    if ($moduleId = Module::getModuleIdByName($carrier['external_module_name'])) {
        $carrier['extraContent'] = Hook::exec('displayCarrierExtraContent', ['carrier' => $carrier], $moduleId);
    }
}
```

So if i set **is_module** to 1 to all my carriers directly from DB then on frontend checkout page, no carriers is being displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've already done something like this in the last 2 year as prestashop developer.
The truth is that you can't achieve what you want by "respecting" prestashop processes.

Maybe you can hook using a module the `hookDisplayCarrierExtraContent($data)` and then return the 2 radios if carrier is certain one (use $data).
But you can't handle a form submit or something else, or include it to prestashop checkout data.
But what you can do as workaround, for example, is the following.

In your module, as I said, hook the extra content, render a template with the 2 radios. Hook displayHeader too and use `$this->context->controller->addJS()` to add your own js if the current controller is the checkout one.

Then in this JS code you can handle the "change" event of the radios and send an ajax request to your module.
You can create inside {your_module}/controllers/front/ a controller called, for example, radio-choose and handle the js ajax request by saving inside your own table the choosen one.

Obviously you  can disable the "next" button in checkout untill one of the two radios are selected, or maybe you can just set a radio button as default one to simplify.

For example your table "ps_cart_choosen_radio" could look like this |id_cart|choosen_radio|.

Then you have all the data you needed. When a cart is converted into an order you will have inside Order object (and ps_orders table as well) the id_cart.

Just select / join choosen radio from your own table by using order's id_cart.

```
"SELECT choosen_radio FROM ps_cart_choosen_radio WHERE id_cart = {$order.id_cart}"
```

If you need to show data depending on choosen_radio in frontend you can hook everywhere an order is present and select these data. Or maybe you can edit carrier name in ps_orders table by adding a piece of string. Let' say carrier is "express" and customer choosed "24h". You can update that column with carrier name by changing it to "express-24h" so around the whole prestashop ecosystem everybody will see that's a 24h choice.

Remember that the carrier name related to an order is not the carrier name inside the carriers table. So you can edit it without having trouble.

All these problems comes from the "need" to show some nested choices instead of listing all these in the main selections. In that case it would be easy (just create carrier in the prestashop backoffice)

Comment: Thanks Damiano for your reply. But when we execute ajax request on selecting **Locker Pickup** then i am successfully able to send ajax request to custom controller but how can we update shipping price programatically on checkout page at here https://prnt.sc/4QWI8GxItPZs